# Query all tables in a sql data base with Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am using python with sqlite3, and I have problem in reading out tables in a data base created by myself.

The data base is created using the below code snippet

```
con = sqlite3.connect(folderdir + dbFileName)
#Create a cursor
c = con.cursor()
#Below code creates the data base. I later need to extract all tablename in 
my data base
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tablename + ' (Bord text, Date 
    text, Time text, ID integer, Menu text, Qty integer, Price real, 
    Time_kitchen text, TableActive integer)')

c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + tablename + ''' (Bord, Date, Time, TableActive) 
    VALUES(?,?,?,?)''',
    (tablename, date, tabletime, 1))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

If above code is called many times with different tablename variables, I get a database.db file containing many tablenames. My problem is, even using the sqlite_master, I cannot read out all the tablenames. I use the below code to read out

```
import sqlite3
#I have verified that I can connect successfully to the database file
con = sqlite3.connect(dbFilePath + "/" + dbFileName + ".db")
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT ALL Name FROM sqlite_master")
rows = c.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

The print returned nothing although I know for sure that I have a database with multiple tablenames in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I know for sure that I have a database with multiple tablenames*...how do you know this? Did you run same sqlite_master command in SQLite command line (not Python)? Also, is `folderdir + dbFileName` the same exact as `dbFilePath + "/" + dbFileName + ".db"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the file whose name is given to `connect()` does not exist, SQLite will happily create a new, empty database for you.

Ensure that the file name is correct; and it should not be a relative file name to avoid a dependency on the current directory.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing it out for me. It is correct, there is nothing wrong with the SQL statement, it created another db file, which of course did not contain any tables.